# modulus operator with unsigned chars

Tags: c, modulus

Trying to get some code working and the modulus doesn't want to do what I want it to do... which means I have it wrong.

I have `unsigned char`s that I'm trying to seperate out hours/minutes/seconds into so I can display them on the screen in Ascii.

The variable `secs` is an`unsigned int`.  Everything else is an`unsigned char`. I want the results in `unsigned char`s so not to waste memory.  Working in an embedded environment.

Anyone care to look at the code snippet and tell me what I've done wrong?

```
hours   = secs/3600.0;
minutes =(secs/60.0)-(hours*3600);
seconds =secs-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60);

sec_ones    =(unsigned char)((seconds%10));
sec_tens    =(unsigned char)((seconds-sec_ones)%100);
min_ones    =(unsigned char)(minutes%10);
min_tens    =(unsigned char)((minutes-min_ones)%100);
hrs_ones    =(unsigned char)(hours%10);
hrs_tens    =(unsigned char)((hours-hrs_ones)%100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
minutes =(secs/60.0)-(hours*3600);
```

should be

```
minutes =(secs/60.0)-(hours*60);
```

Other than that, it works for small enough input: http://ideone.com/VPKP1

There are some things that I'd change, though. For example, there's no point doing a double division and then assigning the result back to `unsigned char`, you might as well just do integer division.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned it is an embedded program.

```
seconds = secs-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60);
```

`hours` is an `unsigned char` promoted to `int` in the expression `hours*3600`.

If your are working with 16-bit `int` you will have problems with the above line. On two's complement system 16-bit `int` range go from `-32768` to `32767` which mean you have an overflow when  `hours` is `>= 10`.

Answer (score 0):

first, you do your computations with `double` since you are using `double` constants.

then the modulus calculations will not be done as `unsigned char` because it is a narrow type. generally it will first be promoted to `int` and then the calculations will be done.

Usually you are better off by using `unsigned int` directly for all your variables. `char` types are only useful when you want to save space.

Comment: It's embedded programming so we've been told to use chars unless we have a really good reason.

Answer (score 0):

your program is just bad written, try to do that, it run correctly

```
unsigned int secs = 5000;
unsigned char sec_ones,sec_tens,min_ones,min_tens,hrs_ones,hrs_tens, hours, minutes, seconds;

hours   = secs/3600.0;
minutes =(secs/60.0)-(hours*60);
seconds =secs-(hours*3600)-(minutes*60);

sec_ones    =(unsigned char)((seconds%10));
sec_tens    =(unsigned char)(seconds/10);
min_ones    =(unsigned char)(minutes%10);
min_tens    =(unsigned char)(minutes/10);
hrs_ones    =(unsigned char)(hours%10);
hrs_tens    =(unsigned char)(hours/100);

printf("%.1u%.1u:%.1u%.1u:%.1u%.1u\n",hrs_tens,hrs_ones,min_tens,min_ones,sec_tens,sec_ones );
```

Comment: Baddly written?  Never would have guessed that.  Good thing I asked for help.  Yes, your responce DID help.  I realized a calc error. 3am coding never a good idea.  Thanks.